# Multiple Smart Pointer References to Same Object

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

After much time, I believe that the problem with my code is that I have multiple smart pointer references to the same object which causes the object to be deleted by more than one smart pointer. I have condensed the code as much as I can without taking away from the idea of the program.

Currently, the error that I am getting is a seg. fault. I believe that my double references get created at this line.

```
newProtocol->SetCPU(CPUPtr(this));
```

Is my problem a double reference to the same object and if so, how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

#include "boost/weak_ptr.hpp"
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class TCPProtocol;
class CPU;
class TCPConnection;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<TCPProtocol> TCPProtocolPtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<CPU> CPUPtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> TCPConnectionPtr;


class Protocol
{
    public:
    string GetName() const;
    string _name;
};

class TCPProtocol : public Protocol
{
    public:
        static TCPProtocolPtr Create(){return(TCPProtocolPtr(new TCPProtocol()));}
        static TCPProtocolPtr Create(const TCPProtocol &Protocol
        {
            return(TCPProtocolPtr(new TCPProtocol(Protocol)));
        }
        void SetCPU(boost::shared_ptr<CPU> CPU){ _CPU = CPU; }

    protected:
        boost::weak_ptr<CPU> _CPU;
};

class CPU
{
    public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, TCPProtocolPtr> ProtocolMap;

    public:
        CPU(const CPU& obj);
        CPU(TCPConnectionPtr connection){}
        static CPUPtr Create(const TCPConnectionPtr connection)
        {
            return(CPUPtr(new CPU(connection)));
        }
        void AddProtocol(const TCPProtocolPtr ProtocolPtr);
        void SetCPU(boost::shared_ptr<CPU> CPU);
        ProtocolMap Protocols();
        const ProtocolMap Protocols() const;
        ProtocolMap _Protocols;
};

 class TCPConnection
 {
      public:
          static TCPConnectionPtr Create()
          {
              return(TCPConnectionPtr(new TCPConnection()));
          }
          void SetVersion(int version){ _version = version; }       

      private: 
          int _version;
};

int main()
{
    //Create a connection to an CPU
    TCPConnectionPtr CPUConnection = TCPConnection::Create();

    //Define needed connection parameters
    CPUConnection->SetVersion(123);

    //Create an CPU
    CPUPtr CPU = CPU::Create(CPUConnection);

    //Create an instance of TCPProtocol
    TCPProtocolPtr ProtocolPtr = TCPProtocol::Create();

    //Add the protocol to the CPU
    CPU->AddProtocol(ProtocolPtr);
}

CPU::CPU(const CPU& obj) 
{
    //Iterate through rhs map and insert its pairs into the lhs map
    for(ProtocolMap::const_iterator i = obj._Protocols.begin(); 
         i != obj._Protocols.end(); ++i)
    {
        TCPProtocolPtr p = TCPProtocol::Create();
        *p = *(i->second);
        AddProtocol(p);
    }
}

void CPU::AddProtocol(const TCPProtocolPtr ProtocolPtr)
{
    TCPProtocolPtr newProtocol = TCPProtocol::Create(*ProtocolPtr);
    std::string name = newProtocol->_name;
    newProtocol->SetCPU(CPUPtr(this));
    _Protocols[name] = newProtocol;

}
```

Comment: Without looking at the full code (only at the line you pointed out near the top) it seems you need `enable_shared_from_this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hint from R. Martinho Fernandes in the comments, I used

`boost::enable_shared_from_this<CPU>`

to get rid of the double references. The sections of code that I updated are below.

I publicly inherited from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<>` and created a method called share that would return a reference to the object AND keep the reference count correct.

```
class CPU : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<CPU>
{
   ...
   boost::shared_ptr<CPU> Share()
   {
       return shared_from_this();
   }
};

void CPU::AddProtocol(const TCPProtocolPtr ProtocolPtr)
{
   ...
    newProtocol->SetCPU(CPUPtr(this));
    _Protocols[name] = newProtocol;

}
```

Comment: CPU is still a local variable inside `main`, so you're still double-freeing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Wouldn't I get a seg. fault still if this was the case?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Lack of segmentation fault does not mean your program has no errors. You only get a segmentation fault if you are _lucky_; it is the OS stopping you from overwriting segments of memory that are not yours. However, if you're overwriting segments of memory that _are_ yours, it can't detect that — even if those are segments of memory that you didn't mean to overwrite.